Can I change Safari's dispatch thread limit of 512?
When trying to launch Safari on M2 Macbook Air with 24GB Ram, Activity Monitor shows that the thread count quickly jumps to about 309, and then 517, at which it becomes non-responsive. When reading the error report I see that Dispatch has reached it's thread limit of 512. Can I change the thread limit for Safari, and would raising or lowering it help keep the process from hanging so that it can open?

Presumably, when you launch it, it is trying to reload hundreds of windows/tabs from the last session? You can hold the Shift key when it launches to clear the old document state.

Yes it is. When I held the shift key it was not working. Apple released an update, Sonoma 14.5, that allowed me to open Safari without issue, though it was delayed. I believe now it was a bug in Sonoma 14.4.1 due to other reading I did. Thank You for Your response.

For future reference: there are other ways you can clear the saved state.
